# How can I recreate the default frontpage view?

Tags: views

I accidentally deleted my default frontpage view I was using on a Drupal 8 site, and I can't find how to either recreate it or which path to set on a new view to have it as front page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important point - this is in Drupal 8.

Also, I know about setting a custom path to be the homepage, but I wanted to know how to set the custom view path to just www.mysite.com, for example, without the extra /node.

Comment: This could happen to anyone. I just uninstalled HAL module + Rest which deleted the Frontpage view as I added a Rest export display to /node path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate new view with any path and then just make it your default front page.

Steps:

1. Log into your Drupal 7 dashboard
2. In the top menu, click Configuration
3. Under System click Site Information
4. Under FRONT PAGE, adjust the Default front page setting **(Put you new page view path)**
5. Click the Save Configuration button at the bottom of the page to
   save these settings.

Follow [this link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/homepage/change-front-page) for proper steps with images.

Comment: @WOLF: Sorry mate but not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve but if you want to make page view as your front page then above steps will work for Drupal 8 also.

Comment: The question is about Drupal 8 _and_ question was about deleted view so there is no Frontpage left to adjust.

Comment: I feel the question is more about recreating a front page view which is accidentally deleted. Above steps provide information on setting page view as your default front page. Works for Drupal 7 and 8.

Answer (score 4):

Find the file **/core/modules/node/config/optional/views.view.frontpage.yml**

Next import its content by pasting this at **/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import**