# Is there way to rearrange node on front page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I tried use weight module but it arrange node only on admin interface. Is there way set weight to node on front page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recreate the default Views Frontpage?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197176/how-can-i-recreate-the-default-views-frontpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create views with weight sorting nodes and set it as front page

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest if you create a view and list that on the homepage. I believe the listing of nodes on `/node` (the default homepage) are in reverse chronological by created date.

The checkbox "Sticky" under publish settings might be helpful, but a View would give you the most reliable results.